# Xorg eating my CPU - how do I fix or at least diagnose the problem?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xorg

I have xubuntu 14.04 installed on a desktop that is a few years old.

Often, xorg, will start using 70 to 100 %CPU (according to `top`).  When this happens, everything responds slowly and annoyingly.  (the CPU usage stays high even when I'm not doing anything)

What causes this?  Or, how do I tell what's causing this in my case?

~~~~~

UPDATE:

At aquaherd's suggestion, I tried closing my brouser, which did cause Xorg to drop back down.  However, the tools I use for work are web-based, so simply not using them is not an option.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What graphics card and driver are you using?

Comment: From lspci: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710 [Radeon HD 4550] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])   I don't know how to tell what driver I'm using.

Comment: @the_Seppi when I pull up the "additional drivers" in settings, it says "no proprietary drives in use" and "no additional drivers available" if that helps.

Comment: I see the same on a Core 2 Duo from 2007 with an even older AMD 4350 passive card. The culprit is always flash content on a web page, even when nothing goes on. Closing all browser windows helps.

Comment: @aquaherd - closing firefox did the trick.  However, my job is web-based, so avoiding firefox isn't a solution.  How do I fix it?

Comment: Best idea is to reduce the number of tabs, add the ad- flash- or script-blocker extensions to firefox, add exception rules for your work pages and experiment, perhaps even with other browsers.